# Header fixed bootstrap on touch device

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, touch, device

I used sticky js plugin for my bootstrap template. All work fine, but when I tested on touch device is problem. Because when I scroll down my menu fixed only when scroll is stopped. And this problem when I what to call some animation on my site.

How I can fixed? If this really?

Comment: No code = No answers.

Comment: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/11560#issuecomment-29909700